# Problem Scraping newegg.ca with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have scraped several websites in the past however the structure of newegg.ca is different than any other. I use BeautifulSoup to extract only the name and price of the product. 
The website I am trying to scrape is https://www.newegg.ca/p/N82E16875606157

So far I have scraped the title using:

```
page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

global ng_title
ng_title = page_soup.find(id="grpDescrip_h").get_text().strip()
print(ng_title)
```

Output:

```
Huawei P30 4G LTE Cell Phone 6.1" Breathing Crystal 128GB 6GB RAM
```

But I got stuck on extracting the price. Perhaps I need to implement a for loop? Or there is another way.

I'd appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need selenium for this, price exists right in HTML!
Try inspecting the HTML first, before you bring out the big guns. Use Ctrl + U to view the page source then Ctrl + F to search for price `949`, you'll see the price:

```html
<div itemprop='offers' itemscope itemtype='//schema.org/Offer'>
                                <meta itemprop='price' content='949.00' />
                                <meta itemprop='priceCurrency' content='CAD' />
                              </div>
```

Then:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.newegg.ca/p/N82E16875606157'
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()
html = res.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
price = float(soup.select_one('[itemprop=price]')['content'])
print(price)
```

output:

```
949.0
```

Answer (score 2):

As other answers mentioned this is basically because the content of page is being loaded by help of JavaScript and getting source code with help of urlopener or request will not load that dynamic part.

So here I have a way around of it, actually you can make use of **selenium** to let the dynamic content load and then get the source code from there and the parse it using BeautifulSoup. After you have the complete source code parsed by the browser, you can do whatever you want with it. Here is the code that actually give the result you expected. But you will need to setup [selenium web driver](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html)

```
from lxml import html
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver


def parse(url):
    response = webdriver.Firefox()
    response.get(url)
    sleep(3)
    sourceCode=response.page_source
    return  sourceCode


year =2019
soup = BeautifulSoup(parse("https://www.newegg.ca/p/N82E16875606157"),'lxml')
##Do with whatever you want with the source code
```

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking an easier solution is selenium instead of bs4 like this,

```
from lxml import html
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver


def parse(url):
    response = webdriver.Chrome()
    response.get(url)
    sleep(3)
    name = response.find_element_by_xpath(' //*[@id="grpDescrip_75-606-157"]')
    price = response.find_element_by_xpath(' //*[@id="landingpage-price"]/div/div/ul/li[3]')
    details = response.find_element_by_xpath(' //*[@id="synopsis"]/div[4]/div/div[9]/ul')


    print(name.text)
    print(price.text)
    print(details.text)



    sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    parse('https://www.newegg.ca/p/N82E16875606157')
```

What do you think?

Comment: Looks good. I'm still struggling to get selenium working on my headless ubuntu :S

Comment: I was checking newegg phones anyways the xpath selectors are the same for any model phone for price, and detail and the name selector only varies by the stock item. So you should be able to write a script that pulls a range of stock numbers then a for loop to batch this.  IE apple iphone selector is  //*[@id="grpDescrip_75-100-569”]  with 75-100-569 being the stock number. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I gave up trying to use qtwebkit as they deprecated it and easy installation wasn't possible.

On suggestion of Chuck LaPress I looked into selenium and struggled to get it working on ubuntu server 18. In the end it turned out to be very simple:

```
sudo apt install chromium-browser
sudo apt install chromium-chromedriver
pip install lxml selenium
```

Then the following code will work!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/chromium-browser'
options.add_argument("headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

url = 'https://www.newegg.ca/p/N82E16875606157'
driver.get(url);
sleep(3)

name = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#grpDescrip_h span")
price = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#landingpage-price .price-current")

print(name.text)
print(price.text)
```

Comment: Ok so that doesn't work having tried it. The page is being rendered using javascript unfortunately.

Comment: Right. So I'm assuming there's no straightforward way to do this?